# How do I build Allegro?

Tags: compiling, c++

I'm trying to build allegro on 12.04 but it continues to give me error, I've downloaded the tar.gz folder of version 5.0.7 and installed cmake, what else do I need? And how do I proceed?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I created a new directory under allegro file, called it buid, cd build from terminal and typed
cmake ..
this is the reponse after some lines of processing
'X11 support requires Xcursor library'.

Comment: http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/607854 That might help. You could answer it yourself if it works.

Comment: All ok now, I'm not sure how I did it, cause I had already installed xcursor.dev before, and deleted the buil folder more than once, but maybe I didn't remove the folder-or-the cache txt after xcursor. Thanks

Comment: I had this error now, on the final stage, when I used 'make install'
'Install the project...

-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"

-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/liballegro.so.5.0.7

CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:48 (FILE):

  file INSTALL cannot copy file

  "/home/imagination3/.allegro/Build/lib/liballegro.so.5.0.7" to

  "/usr/local/lib/liballegro.so.5.0.7".



make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: See edited answer. Use sudo.

Answer (score 2):

From the top-level folder:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev
cd build
rm -rf *
cmake ..
```

In the end, run `sudo make install`

Comment: Reading the error I understood myself i needed to use sudo, thinking twice before posting would be better, haha. Thank you all, now time to figure how to use allegro.

Comment: @Temitope Since this post answers the question, I recommend marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking the green check mark to the left of it). This will help others who are searching help with this problem (or similar problems).